# Calling A Custom API From Table's Insert Function Windows Azure

Tags: api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using windows azure in order to manage my application's data.

I have a custom API called 'shared' that contains app the code handles push notifications.
from another API, I can call this method using this code:

```
var operations = require('./shared').operations;
operations["sendPush"](/*parameters*/);
```

When I call the same code from a table's *'insert'* script I get this error:

```
Error in callback for table '*****'. Error: Cannot find module './shared'
[external code]
at Object.sendPush [as success] (</table/*****.insert.js>:57:30)
[external code]
```

Somebody knows how to fix it?

I think the secret as at the url *'./shared'*, cause from an API, it on the same path but from table the path is different.

Does anyone knows what is the path for URL requests to add a table row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suceed.
By creating a GIT repo I could access to the shared folder.
This folder used for things just like this.
You can see a documentation in the readme file inside shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it could be a scoping issue because you are in the callback for your insert script?

You could try moving `var operations = require('./shared').operations;` to the start of your script, before the insert operation.

Answer (score 1):

Shared scripts should reside in the **service/shared** folder. Then you can require them from other scripts using a relative path, like so:

```
require('../shared/mysharedscript.js')
```